# How do you copy a file to multiple devices using ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I have about 20,000 Android tablets that I wish to copy about 10 GB of data on. I have gotten ten 50 ports USB hubs which takes about 10 hrs to drag, paste and copy 1 hub. All my devices are using the same serial number.

Is there a way I can push them simultaneously?

Comment: i have tried adb push command but i get more than one devices or emulator connected. 

I also tried adb -s serial push command i got more than 1 devices connected.

Comment: `i have about 20000 Android tablets` Wait, seriously?

Comment: And all of them have the same serial number?

Comment: You should use a scripting language to query through all attached devices and push your files using a loop. There is no other way i think...

Comment: Yes its i got them from china

Comment: @pavlos please how do i go about this

Comment: @TimCooper aside from `20000`, it's good question. But maybe he has so many devices there (still, 500 still would take a moment to plug) and a bit of current. And I also wonder how people would execute such massive deployment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this script for example. The usage is the same you just type adb+  and your command will be executed on all attached devices!

[ADB+](https://gist.github.com/christopherperry/3208109)

Usage:

```
./adb+ push local_file remote_path
```

And it will push the file to all your devices! Remember its a bash script so you need a Linux distro maybe. If you want a Windows script let me know!

Comment: Thanks Palvos however kindly guide me on how to run this script

Comment: Please i wont mins a windows script aswell

Comment: Actually i cant find one right now but i guess you can find someone who can convert it to batch script!

Comment: i added the scriptas adb+.sh to /usr/local/bin 

when i type adb+.sh (noting happens) but adb+ it says no command found do you mean adb form...........

Comment: I mentioned above the usage, and also you can see how to use it in the link too! just type ./adb+ followed by your command!

Comment: Yayy it worked thanks 

What i did was (ubuntu)

gedit /usr/local/bin/adb+.sh

COPY & Paste then save

reboot

use- adb+.sh devices (or any adb command) 

however it copies 1 after the other not simultaneously

will use this for now but pleaes let me know wen a script that will copy simultaneously is available

Comment: It cannnot be done simultaneously as i can understand.There must be some kind of limitation that blocks simultaneous pushes.If i find one that does it simultaneously i will let you know.Consider accepting my answer if it helped you! Thanks!

Comment: Done! i have a script that i use to copy simultaneously before (not using adb but through mount) is there a way we can merge them if u want me to send it pls send ur email address

Comment: You can find it at my Profile!

Comment: no its not there alternatively pls send a mail to abadmus@netit.com.ng i will reply by pasting it there